# How i can retrieve this array of images from json?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have his **json** and i need to retrieve array of images from `images` Variable..

this my **json** :

```
    {
id: 215,
title: " this is title",
image: "1464958558.jpg",
description: "description",
images: "["1464958558.jpg","1464958559.jpg","1464958561.jpg","1464958563.jpg","1464958564.jpg","1464958568.jpg","1464958569.jpg","1464958570.jpg","1464958573.jpg","1464958574.jpg"]",
user_name: "user name",
telephone: "0123456789"
}
```

i want to retrieve this images array and display it in grid view... and i can't find any response in `logcat`

my doInBackGround()

```
 @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // Building Parameters
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        ID = mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query._ID);

        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(String.valueOf(Config.BASE_URL));

        //jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + 373); //or url + ID
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground Image: "  + String.valueOf(Config.BASE_URL));

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                GridItem item;
                item = new GridItem();
                Log.i(TAG, "parseResult: " + jsonObj);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                    // if (response != null) {
                    String images = jsonObj.getString("images");

                    item.setImage(IMAGE_LINK + images);//IMAGE_LINK +

                    Log.i(TAG, "parseResult: " + IMAGE_LINK + " " +  images);

                    mGridData.add(item);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
        return null;
    }
```

dose i retrieve data correctly ?

Comment: Images json object is string or json array? In your code is string.

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki  should my braces in json be in  outside from double qutetion " " ?

Comment: Exactly, then you can parse it as json array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is images json object string or json array? In your code is string.

 If WebService changes are possible, request to given you a json array of `images`, this is best practice. 
If not possible you must parse json `image` object with regex.

Answer (score 0):

`images` should be a [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html), and hence you can do that to parse it (inside your for loop!):

```
JSONArray imagesJSON = jsonObj.getJSONArray("images");
for(int k = 0 ; k<imagesJSON.length() ; k++){
   String image = imagesJSON.getString(k);
   item.setImage(IMAGE_LINK + image);//IMAGE_LINK +
   Log.i(TAG, "parseResult: " + IMAGE_LINK + " " +  image);
   mGridData.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No your doing wrong just try below code

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        JSONArray arrayObj = jsonObj.getJSONArray("images");

        for(int i=0;i<arrayObj.length();i++)
        {
            String item = arrayObj.getString(i);
            // now you use item string where you want
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```